# How to get memory used(RAM used) using Linux command?

Tags: centos, memory, cpanel

I am trying to retrieve memory used(RAM) in percentage using Linux commands. My cpanel shows Memory Used which I need to display on a particular webpage.

From forums, I found out that correct memory can be found from the following:

```
free -m
```

Result:

```
-/+ buffers/cache:        492       1555
```

-/+ buffers/cache: contains the correct memory usage. I don't know how to parse this info or if there is any different command to get the memory used in percentage.

Comment: That was answered over here already!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585978/linux-command-for-percentage-of-memory-that-is-free

e.g: 

`free | grep Mem | awk '{print $4/$2 * 100.0}'`

Comment: @szboardstretcher I like this one: `$ free | awk '/Mem/{printf("used: %.2f%"), $3/$2*100} /buffers\/cache/{printf(", buffers: %.2f%"), $4/($3+$4)*100} /Swap/{printf(", swap: %.2f%"), $3/$2*100}'`

Comment: Without knowing what you need the number for it is hard to tell you what number you should use. However in many cases any of those numbers is just very naive and requires trend and context information.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Here is sample output from free:

```
% free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:      24683904   20746840    3937064     254920    1072508   13894892
-/+ buffers/cache:    5779440   18904464
Swap:      4194236        136    4194100
```

The first line of numbers (`Mem:`) lists

- `total` memory
- `used` memory
- `free` memory
- usage of `shared`
- usage of `buffers`
- usage filesystem caches (`cached`)

In this line `used` *includes the buffers and cache* and this impacts free.
This is not your "true" free memory because the system will dump cache if needed to satisfy allocation requests.

The next line (`-/+ buffers/cache:`) gives us the actual used and free memory as if there were no buffers or cache.

The final line (`Swap`) gives the usage of swap memory. There is no buffer or cache for swap as it would not make sense to put these things on a physical disk.

To output used memory (minus buffers and cache) you can use a command like:

```
% free | awk 'FNR == 3 {print $3/($3+$4)*100}'
23.8521
```

This grabs the third line and divides used/total * 100.

And for free memory:

```
% free | awk 'FNR == 3 {print $4/($3+$4)*100}' 
76.0657
```

Comment: Is "-/+ buffers/cache:    5779440   18904464" correct RAM usage/status of server?

Comment: Strictly speaking, no, but practically speaking, yes.  The actual memory usage is the 2nd line (used: 20746840) but part of that memory use is buffers and cache which are just to speed up response times on your system.  The third line (used: 5779440) gives you the amount of memory actually used by programs and it is this memory figure that determines how much more your programs can allocate.  If your goal is to get free / used memory in a sense of what programs are actually using and what you can actually allocate, then yes, line 3 is correct for you.

Comment: Note that with more recent versions of `free`, `-/+ buffers/cache` is completely omitted intentionally, and the value shown in the `used` column now excludes the buffers and cache by default. See here: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1158828

Answer (score 11):

I am going to mention on how to parse the information on `free` command. To find the percentage, you can use as suggested in the other 2 answers.

This is clearly explained [here](http://www.linuxnix.com/2013/05/find-ram-size-in-linuxunix.html). I would try to explain from what I have in my system.

```
free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7869       4402       3466          0        208       3497
-/+ buffers/cache:        696       7173
Swap:         3999        216       3783
```

Now, let us see what the various numbers actually represent.

**Line1**

- *7869* Indicates memory/physical RAM available for my machine.
- *4402* Indicates memory/RAM used by my system.
- *3466* Indicates Total RAM free and available for new process to run.
- *0*    Indicates shared memory. This column is obsolete and may be removed in future 
        releases of free.
- *208*  Indicates total RAM buffered by different applications in Linux.
- *3497* Indicates total RAM used for Caching of data for future purpose.

**Line2**

```
-/+ buffers/cache:        696       7173
```

**How to calculate the values 696 and 7173 obtained in Line2?**

**Total used** (*4402*) - **Total buffer RAM** (*208*) - **Total RAM for caching**(*3497*) should constitute the **Actual used RAM** in the system. It returns me *697* which is the *actual used RAM* output in the second line.

Now, **Total Available** (*7869*) - **Actual Used** (*696*) should give you the **free memory** which is *7173* in this case which is also got as output in the second line.

Answer (score 9):

Though a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585978/linux-command-for-percentage-of-memory-that-is-free) as pointed by @szboardstretcher , my preference from the solutions (in the original question) is the one below, specially since you want to parse to a webpage.

```
$ free | awk '/Mem/{printf("used: %.2f%"), $3/$2*100} /buffers\/cache/{printf(", buffers: %.2f%"), $4/($3+$4)*100} /Swap/{printf(", swap: %.2f%"), $3/$2*100}'
```

Output:

```
used: 82.68%, buffers: 42.81%, swap: 1.27%
```

Comment: FYI I get the following using this ```used: 96.00%, buffers: 26.53%awk: (FILENAME=- FNR=4) fatal: division by zero attempted```

Comment: What's the full command used? I checked it in centos.

Comment: Sorry for the formatting but here you go `$ cat /etc/issue
CentOS release 6.7 (Final)`
`$ free | awk '/Mem/{printf("used: %.2f%"), $3/$2*100} /buffers\/cache/{printf(", buffers: %.2f%"), $4/($3+$4)*100} /Swap/{printf(", swap: %.2f%"), $3/$2*100}'
used: 12.91%, buffers: 96.24%awk: (FILENAME=- FNR=4) fatal: division by zero attempted
$ free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:      15429704    1991416   13438288        164     151556    1259584
-/+ buffers/cache:     580276   14849428 
Swap:            0          0          0 `

Comment: For some  versions of awk (mawk), the percent sign needs to be doubled to print it, otherwise awk throws an error, like this:
    printf("used: %.0f%%"), $3/$2*100
This works with both mawk and gawk.

Answer (score 4):

```
free | awk '/Mem/{printf("used: %.2f%"), $3/$2*100} /buffers\/cache/{printf(", buffers: %.2f%"), $4/($3+$4)*100} /Swap/{printf(", swap: %.2f%\n"), $3/$2*100}'
```

Adds a new line after the swap number

Answer (score 3):

Note, `free` 3.3 and above does not have a `-/+ buffers/cache:` line, so the older answers won't work.  In 3.3 `free` compares used vs availalble in the "Mem" line.
The following will work for both old and new versions of `free`.

```
free |  awk '$1 == "Mem:" {x= $7/($3+$7)*100} $2 == "buffers/cache:" {x= $4/($3+$4)*100} $1 == "Swap:" {print x}'
```

Answer (score 2):

For upto CentOS 7 You can try

```
cat /proc/meminfo
```

to see real usage of memory by processes.